# UNIX - syntax error in my main

Tags: c, unix, system

Im getting a syntax error in the following main statement...

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
```

The error says "syntax error near unexpected token `('".

However, as you can see, there are the right amount of parentheses there. What's the issue?

Thanks!

More code:

```
/*Core Dump Program*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
 {
  struct rlimit limit;

  limit.rlim_cur = 0;
  limit.rlim_max = 0;
  if (setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &limit) == -1){
    printf("Error preventing core dump errno=%d\n", errno);
    exit(10);
  }
  else {
    printf("The current core limit is %llu\n", limit.rlim_cur);
    printf("The core max limit is %llu\n", limit.rlim_max);
    exit(0);
  }
  if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_FSIZE, &limit) == -1){
    printf("getlimit() failed with errno=%d\n", errno);
    exit(1);
  }
  else {
    printf("The current core limit is %llu\n", limit.rlim_cur);
    printf("The core max limit is %llu\n", limit.rlim_max);
    exit(0);

  }
  if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_CPU, &limit) == -1){
    exit(1);
  }
  else {
    printf("The current core limit is %llu\n", limit.rlim_cur);
    printf("The core max limit is %llu\n", limit.rlim_max);
    exit(0);
  }

  if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit) == -1){
      printf("Error preventing core dump errno=%d\n", errno);
      exit(1);
    }
  else {
      printf("The current core limit is %llu\n", limit.rlim_cur);
      printf("The core max limit is %llu\n", limit.rlim_max);
      exit(0);
  }

  if (getrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &limit) == -1){
    printf("Error preventing core dump errno=%d\n", errno);
    exit(1);
  }
  else {
    printf("The current core limit is %llu\n", limit.rlim_cur);
    printf("The core max limit is %llu\n", limit.rlim_max);
    exit(0);

  }
  }
```

Comment: Something earlier in the source, obviously.

Comment: deleted carats and the # symbols in the includes BTW

Comment: @D. Spigle: You can leave them if they're in a code block. It will display properly.

Comment: @D. Spigle: We need even more code. There is nothing wrong with this code so far except that it doesn't have a terminating brace.

Comment: @D. Spigle - this code works for me when I compile it.

Comment: @D. Spigle: This code compiles for me as well (using GCC).

Comment: hmmmmm. It won't run for me though :/

Comment: @D. Spigle, it most likely means something funky is up with your actual source file that we can't see when you just paste us the code. Could be your text editor doing funky things due to line endings, or random special characters...

Comment: Evidently you did not show it to us exactly as it is in your source file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check your code for "invisible" characters.  Depending on how the file was created, it's possible to get control characters and/or unicode chars that you can't see in your normal text editor's normal operating mode.  Many editors have a "Show Invisible Characters" feature (or something similarly named).  Some editors even have a feature that will find and remove any such chars (e.g. "Zap Gremlins" in [Text Wrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) for OS-X.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I got an error like that its because something contains a special character. Sometimes, when you copy stuff of the web there are characters that the compiler doesn't recognize.

If you are using an IDE I would recommend checking the syntax highlighting and seeing if there is anything odd, such as the quotes don't cause a different color, and replace them.

More info:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887842

Comment: @D. Spigle: You shouldn't need too.